# When do destructors get called in a c++ coroutine?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

In a normal c++ function (not a coroutine), destructors for objects that are in scope at the point the function `return`s are called before control is returned to the calling function (ignoring RVO).

In a c++ coroutine, when are destructors called for objects that are in scope at the time the function reaches a `co_return` statement?

An example with nested coroutines:

```
future<> inner()             | void inner()
{                            | {
  Foo local;                 |   Foo local;
  co_return;                 |   return;
}                            | }
                             |
future<> outer()             | void outer()
{                            | {
  co_await inner();          |   inner();
  cerr << "inner done\n";    |   cerr << "inner done\n";
  co_return;                 |   return;
}                            | }
```

I included the synchronous version on the right.

In the synchronous version `local`'s destructor is called before "inner done" is printed. What is supposed to happen in the coroutine version?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simultaneously extremely simple and very complicated.

The simple version is this: if we assume that this `future` type, and its associated coroutine machinery, does the usual things you might expect out of asynchronous coroutine machinery, then yes, it will behave like the synchronous version.

The real answer depends entirely on what `future` and its associated coroutine machinery *actually does*. Because it *could* do a lot of stuff.

The caller of `inner` assumes that the function is expected to "return" a single "value". But like, it doesn't *have to*. A coroutine could be a generator. A coroutine could be [an *asynchronous* generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535798/734069), where it uses an async process to generate multiple values. And in such a case, merely `co_await`ing on them once doesn't mean that the coroutine has finished execution.

Now in this case, that's not what happens. And maybe your `future` machinery doesn't support this. And that's fine. But if you want to know how coroutines work, the answer is ultimately, "they work the way you *tell them* to work."